# Ubuntu 18.04 not detected upon cloning to 8 TB SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

Hello everybody out there using Ubuntu,

Since I was running out of disk space, I cloned my Ubuntu 18.04 installation from a 4TB SSD (Samsung) to a 8TB SSD (also Samsung) using `dd`.
Afterwards, I expanded the Ubuntu partition from 4TB to 8TB on the SSD using *GParted*.

Although there was a GPT partition table on the 4TB SSD (which was and is booting fine) *GParted* didn't find a partition table initially and asked me whether it should create one. I confirmed it should create a GPT table, which I confirmed with the `sudo parted` command (while having booted to the old 4 TB hard-disk and having attached the new 8 TB one as an external disk with an USB adapter):

```
Model: Samsung Portable SSD T1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8002GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  8002GB  8002GB  ext4
```

In addition, I checked the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdc: 15628053168 sectors, 7.3 TiB
Model: Portable SSD T1 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 77496514-CFD9-4986-81C9-0ADDBD4EF3F9
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15628053134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2669 sectors (1.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  EF02  
   2            4096     15628052479   7.3 TiB     8300
```

However, my Thinkpad X230 does **not** boot from the 8TB SSD with the error message:

```
2100: Detection error on HDD0 (Main HDD)
```

A web search also turned up some results mentioning this could be due to a hardware error, but the 4 TB disk is working fine.
The 8 TB disk also works fine, because I can mount it and open the data I had cloned from the 4 TB one.
However, I can't boot the 8 TB disk.

Which additional diagnostics could I run to pin down the problem?

Please not that I already ran a `fsck -af /dev/sdb2` to rule out potential filesystem errors.

Moreover, I used the *boot-repair* package for *Ubuntu* to fix the problem to no success (despite a positive report of the results).

Comment: With the new SSD, try switching [boot mode in the BIOS](https://download.lenovo.com/km/media/images/HT500207/bioslegacysupport_20161121020430.PNG) to legacy support or vice versa ... boot in the new mode once before switching it back and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you check, that the physical sector sizes are the same on the two SSDs? Did you use `gdisk` to fix the backup partition table at the tail end of the target drive after cloning? See also [this link (1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032294/clonezilla-disk-to-disk-clone-from-hdd-with-ubuntu-to-hdd-with-windows-on-new/1032401#1032401), [this link (2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097683/lubuntu-18-10-x64-installed-on-usb-stick-clone-to-usb-stick-2/1097733#1097733) and [this link (3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248)

Comment: Post link to Summary Report (BIS) from Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually turned out not to be caused by the new 8 TB SSD, but rather by an additional mSATA, for which the ThinkPad has an additional slot.
Disabling it in `/etc/fstab` solved the problem.